# How to get run/start - process time?

Tags: c++, windows, time, process

I have Windows system and I wuld like to get start/run process time.
This code is get process list.

```
hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
Entry.dwSize = sizeof(Entry);    
Process32First(hSnapshot, &Entry);
do 
{
  //do something
}
while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &Entry));
```

What can I do to get start/run process time?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem. You want to know how much time does the process take to complete?

Comment: Perhaps call `time()` or `gettimeofday()`, or one of quite a few other functions, at the start of the program, and save the results somewhere? Windows probably has its non-POSIX equivalents, too...

Comment: No no no... I have a process list. I would like to get information about process-start time of all process. (similarity "Task manager")

Comment: So.. I don't understand how to use this code.. Can you give me example with my code?